# adding cache to memonized object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memoization

I have Memoized an object and thinking of adding cache to that variable.. is that a required if speed matters?

```
def user_details    
 @_user_details ||= user.profiles.includes(":asso_1,:asso_2,:asso_3")
end
```

adding cache

```
def user_details    
  data = Rails.cache.fetch("#{user.updated_at.to_i}") do
  @_user_details ||= user.profiles.includes(":asso_1,:asso_2,:asso_3")
  end
  @_user_details = data
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your caching key; make it something like: `users_#{user.id}`;

Then you'll need to remove this key on user update.

Also, your user_details method should be something like:

```
def user_details    
  @_user_details ||= Rails.cache.fetch("users_#{user.id}") do
    user.profiles.includes(":asso_1,:asso_2,:asso_3")
  end

  return @_user_details
end
```

(I'm not sure why you want it in `@_user_details` but I kept it like your example)

Your user model should look something like that:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  after_update { Rails.cache.delete(cache_key) }

  def cache_key
    "users_#{self.id}"
  end

  def details
    Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
      self.profiles.includes(":asso_1,:asso_2,:asso_3")
    end
  end
end
```